# Zero-byte files in /usr/local/bin after AMI captured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ansible

I am launching an EC2 instance using [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) and capturing an AMI image. I have verified that these dependencies get installed correctly on the instance. For example, this is what I get on the EC2  instance just before AMI imaging:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-2-3-4:/usr/local/bin$ ansible --version
ansible 1.4.4

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5907 Jan 31 22:20 ansible
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9269 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-doc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29163 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-galaxy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10419 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-playbook
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6916 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-pull
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   714 Jan 31 22:19 aws
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1408 Jan 31 22:19 aws.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   897 Jan 31 22:19 aws_completer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1860 Jan 31 22:19 aws_zsh_completer.sh
```

The problem is that once I capture an AMI and launch a new instance, I all files in `/usr/local/bin` are zero-byte files!

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:20 ansible
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-doc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-galaxy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-playbook
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:20 ansible-pull
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:19 aws
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:19 aws.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:19 aws_completer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 31 22:19 aws_zsh_completer.sh
```

Why are these files being zero'ed out when I create a new instance from the AMI?

Comment: How do you create an AMI image? Is the instance root device EBS backed or EC2 instance store backed? You might want to read through this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html#Using_RootDeviceStorage

Comment: Did you try with an Amazon Linux AMI?  Just create a non empty file under /usr/local/bin, create the AMI and relaunch with the new AMI

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with Ansible, not with AWS. Turns out there's a [documentation bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/5231) in Ansible 1.4.4 where the `ec2_ami` module does not shut down and reboot the instance by default (the docs claim it does!). This causes all sorts of problems with file system integrity.

The fix is to include `no_reboot: no` in the Ansible task.